# How to manually piece together a fraction on excel

Tags: excel, formula, fractions

I'm working with some tallies and would like to manually piece together a fraction that could be read using conditional formatting.

The extracted formula that uses fractional values are as follows:

```
COUNTIFS(Converter!40:40,"Y",Converter!$5:$5,F$5) & " / " & COUNTIFS(Converter!40:40,"Y",Converter!$5:$5,F$5) + COUNTIFS(Converter!40:40,"N",Converter!$5:$5,F$5)
```

Basically, the fraction should look like `a/(a+b)` and I would like all tallied figures to be displayed where applicable, i.e. 2/8 or 20/100.

Unfortunately Excel is only reading this as a date, even if I use the `TEXT()` formula, the figures continue to be read by Excel as dates.

I'd like the conditional formatting to turn red for any figure that's short of "1".

How can I get Excel to read the figures as a fraction? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about some examples of sample data, expected output, actual output.  Suggest you read the HELP page for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question to provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave formatting as a visual aspect that is displayed versus something you should control in your formulas.

What you need to do is select the cell you want to format as a fraction.

[image]

Then you select the fraction amounts that you want.

Edit: If you want to fix the denominator then you need to use a custom format.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply. I expect the denominator to grow up to 60 however using the Cell formatting facility, I assume this would turn 30/60 to 1/3, and the existing formats available on Excel only allows a "defaulted" denominator figure to appear...?

Comment: 30/60 is 1/2. Anyway you might want to check out custom format. There's an example there like # ?? / ??

Comment: Thank you Peng, unfortunately as the denominator is expected to grow up to 60, I can't fix it to a default one. e.g. I would still expect 20/40 or 58/60 at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't get the fractions to work as fractions, luckily what I needed it to do was trigger the conditional formatting, so I ended up using the following conditional formatting formula.

It's a little longer but got me there in the end...

`=AND(RIGHT(D1,(FIND(" ",D1,1)-1))>0,LEFT(D1,(FIND(" ",D1,1)-1))=RIGHT(D1,(FIND(" ",D1,1)-1)))`